# Image change To Responsive Image?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

How to change image to  full Responsive image? i  have following image top of the site page ? trying to change Responsive image ? not working any idea for it ?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>LearningFox</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     table[class=container],
     table[class=content],
     table[class=wrap-table],
     table[class=table],
     table[class=id]
     {
        width: 100% !important; 
     }

}
</style>
</head>
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" RIGHTMARGIN="0">

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="container" >
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="800" height="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="content" >

  <tr bgcolor="#366C88">
    <td colspan="2"   style="background-image:url('../site_conf/images/det_banner.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;" width="100%" height="100" align="right">
    <?php
    if(!is_null($sid)&&$session_error=="none")
    {
        $_SESSION['lms_username']=$lms_username;
    ?>
    <TABLE BORDER="0"  CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="190" class="wrap-table" >
    <TR>
        <TD><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000">Logged in as: <B><?php echo $lms_username; ?></B></TD>
    </TR>
        <?php
        if($lms_groups=="on" && $lms_user_group!=""){
        ?>
        <TR>
            <TD><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><?php echo"$lms_gtitle: "; if($lms_groups=="on"){echo"<B>$lms_user_group</B>";}?></TD>        
        </TR>   
        <TR>
            <TD><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><?php echo "$lms_sgtitle: "; if($lms_groups=="on"){echo"<B>$lms_user_subgroup</B>";}?></TD>

        </TR>   
        <tr>
            <TD><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><?php if($section=="reports" && $report){echo"<A HREF='index.php?section=reports&sid=$sid'>Back to Detailed Reports Section";}?></FONT></TD>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>

    </TABLE>
    <?php

    }
    ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" height="20" bgcolor="" background="images/bg.gif">
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table" >
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <TD align="right"><?php
    if(!is_null($sid)&&$session_error=="none")
    {
    ?><a style=""  href="index.php?section=<?php echo $section; ?>&logout=YES&sid=<?php echo $sid; ?>"><img src="images/logout.png" border="0" align="ABSMIDDLE" alt="Click here to Log Out"></a><?php
    }
    ?></TD>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="198">
    <!---------BEGIN SIDE NAV TABLE------------->
    <table width="198" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="id" >
        <tr valign="top"> 
          <td width="198"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
    <!--<td class="boxcontent" VALIGN="TOP" width="602" style="border:1px solid red;">-->
    <td class="boxcontent" VALIGN="TOP" >
    <?php 
    include($mysection);
    echo("$mysection");
    ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
```

Here update my full code i set remain part Responsive but i cant able to that image part? please any idea about it..how to change that image part change the Responsive design?

Comment: This question, and the code therein, is a complete mess. How has anyone been able to understand, let alone, answer this?

Answer (score 1):

```
background-size: cover;
```

Try this, it should do what you need.

Comment: i need to change Responsive image

Comment: Please try to explain better.

Comment: i  Have used that image my top of the page banner its using login page .i changed login page Responsive .but image not working in Responsive =? when i minimize browser login page its working Responsive.. but not working  image?

Answer (score 0):

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: not working sir. can i use class value  in my code ?

Comment: just use .yourclass instead of html

Comment: What exactly are u getting?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an div with a class.

```
    <div class="resp"></div>
```

With CSS you can do something like :

```
    .resp {
       height: 500px;
       width: 500px;   
       background: url(../img/waddup.png) center center no-repeat fixed;
       background-size: cover; 
    }
```

Booyah.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
td.banner{
    background-image:url('../site_conf/images/det_banner_new.jpg') !important;
}
```

Becuase of using inline style attribute to set background image, Its required to have "important" in you media css.

JQuery:

```
$(window).resize({
    if($(window).width()<768){
        $("td.banner").attr("backgroundImage","url('../site_conf/images/det_banner_new.jpg')");
    }else{
        $("td.banner").attr("backgroundImage","url('../site_conf/images/det_banner_old.jpg')");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following CSS.
Just change the selector to what you want.

```
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```